# why does redirect_to _path provide a HTTP rather than HTTPS url?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Within a Rails 3.0 application, I have a controller with the many methods like this one,

```
class ReviewsController
  # POST "/reviews/new_submit_form"
  def new_submit_for
    # some logic
    redirect_to new_subject_reviews_url(:format => "js")
  end
end

** terminal output **  

Started POST "/reviews/new_submit_form" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-06 11:40:00 -0400
Processing by ReviewsController#new_submit_form as 
Parameters: {"question_sheet_id"=>"23"}
Existing local CAS session detected for "MYNAME@GMAIL.COM". Previous ticket "XX-1111-CjtSMaVpmiqBPsBoufke-plidma41" will be re-used.
Redirected to http://website.org/reviews/new_subject.js
Completed 302 Found in 1ms
```

The issue is the `redirect_to new_subject_reviews_url(:format => "js")` returns a HTTP url rather than a HTTPS url.

I found one solution,  `redirect_to new_subject_reviews_url(:format => "js", :protoco => "https://")`, but this requires me to edit the method through the Rails app. How can I fix this globally within my Rails application without majorly hacking Rails?

Comment: Just to be clear, is this page being loaded via HTTPS in the first place?

Comment: yes, page is loaded via HTTPs in the first place. Maybe more info than needed, but user is first authenticated with CAS and then brought to home page via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find out why, but I found a solution.

```
Ccc360::Application.configure do

   # all the other configs

   # so that redirect_to will have, "https://www.mywebsite.org/xxxxxx"
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :protocol => "https" } 
end
```